# C++ enums with additional data (similarly to ML/Haskell datatypes)

Tags: c++, enums, option-type, variant

I would like to create a function that returns an enumeration value, but just in case of specific values, it also provides some additional data. In SML I would define the return type as

```ml
datatype rettype = A | B | C of data | D of data
```

... where `data` is some previously defined type.

In C++, I can do the following:

```cpp
enum class AuxEnum { A, B, C, D };
using RetType = std::pair<AuxEnum, std::optional<Data>>;
```

While this works, it bothers me that there is no actual connection between the enumeration value and whether additional data is supplied.

Is there a better option?

Comment: You can make `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` actual types (empty `struct`s or `struct`s with a `data` member respectively) and use `std::variant<A, B, C, D>` to get a sum type or does that not match your requirements?

Comment: Yes, I thought about that, too, but it seemed to be excessive to create four different types just for that... Although, as you say, the types can be just empty structs. I'll consider that, thanks.

Comment: You can also use the same type several times as template argument to `enum` and then operate on the `std::variant` via numeric index that could be mapped to the `enum`, but I don't think that will be simpler overall in the end.

Comment: I think I'll go with your original version, with an additional namespace declaration around the four types.

Comment: You are hardly alone. Alas, not today (or at least not without unnecessary  PITA like std::variant). Maybe in C++29.